# Responsive Navigation (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a responsive navigations, and have it working correctly; but what I'm trying to do is to have the navigation work when the screen width is less than 480 or equal to (`#logo` would make responsiveNav appear), otherwise the link would function as a normal link (`#logo` would take you back to `index.html`) This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#logo').click(function() {
        if ($(body).width() < 480) {             
            $('link[href=index.html]').remove();
            $('ul.mobileNav').slideToggle();
            $('ul.mobileNav').css({
                'top': '70px',
                'position': 'relative',
                'marginBottom': '5px'       
            });
        } else {
                $('link[href=index.html]').add();
        }
    });
});
```

The issue is that it does not work. Not sure if I wrote the if conditional right? any thoughts?

Comment: Please create a SSCCE on jsfiddle.net

Comment: @hjpotter92 That's really not necessary in this case. You can tell by looking at his markup that he forgot the quotes around `body` in his `if` statement, no need for a fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `body` in quotes:

```
if ($("body").width() < 480){
...
} else {
...
}
```

More on [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), specifically [element selectors](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/).

Comment: I previously had quote in the markup but i never worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

As Charlie points out you need to put quotes around `body`.

In the question you said less than **or** equal to, therefore you need `...width() <= 480) {...`

Also, if your body takes up the entire width of the screen you can also use `$(window).width` instead of `$("body").width`